# getting HTML source code from webView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm making an iphone app...can I get the source from it in objective-c?

Thanks!
Elijah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get the contents of the current URL in your web view you could have something like this in a UIViewController. I didn't compile this code, so there may be some syntax errors, but this should be a solid starting point for your problem.

```
@interface aViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
    UIWebView *webView;
    NSString *htmlSource;
@end
@implementation aViewController 

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    self.webView.delegate = self;

    NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myurl.com"];
    NSURLRequest *aRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aURL];
    //load the index.html file into the web view.
    [self.webView loadRequest:aRequest];
}    
//This is a delegate method that is sent after a web view finishes loading content.
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSLog(@"finished loading");
    self.htmlSource = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[webView request] HTTPBody] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}

@end
```

Comment: Two requests to the same URL doubles your chances of an error response, adds the potential for inconsistent responses, and increases your use of the radio.  Caching might mitigate these issues, but why depend on that when you already have the data?

Comment: What are you referring to by two requests to the same URL?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean.  I've updated it to retrieve the source based on the HTTPBody of the UIWebView's NSURLRequest.

Comment: The request property is the request that the web view sent to the server to obtain the content, not the response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can get anything from the web view that JavaScript can return using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:.  Try something along the lines of

```
document.lastChild.outerHTML
```

The document will likely have two child nodes; the first will be the DOCTYPE, and the second the <html> element.